# Lucene.Net Product Keyword Search

Tags: sql-server-2008, search, lucene, lucene.net, keyword

I am looking for a product search engine. Everyone has suggested Lucene.NET, but I am wondering if it works how I might expect. I want to feed the Lucene documents the fields from the MSSQL database so that five different product fields are searchable.

1) Can I create documents from a SQL database?

All of the samples I can find use hardcoded values. I want to populate the documents from five product columns from the database.

How do I set the text var so that it takes everything from the database in that particular field?

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.Add(new Field("id", i.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO));
doc.Add(new Field("ProductDescription", text, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.TOKENIZED));
writer.AddDocument(doc);
```

2) How do I search multiple fields with one query?

```
var queryParser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, "ProductName", analyzer);
queryParser += new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, "ProductDescription", analyzer);
queryParser += new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, "ProductSpecification", analyzer);
queryParser += new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, "ProductDetails", analyzer);
queryParser += new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, "ProductKeywords", analyzer);

var query = queryParser.Parse("plasma tv");
//should return results for Sony Plasma TV, Sony HD Plasma, Sony 32 inch Plasma, Philips Plasma TV
```

Any tutorials on MS SQL to Lucene out there?

Comment: "Everyone has suggested Lucene.NET". I really suggest that you go with Solr. Solr is an HTTP over Lucene and works excellent with database indexing and you dont have to write any code. It can be regarded as a Search Server. You will be able to answer both of your questions yourself when you work with Solr. I know you might have spent some time on Lucene. Just download Solr and give it a try for half a day. Let me know the feedback.

Comment: Interesting. Is this the site: http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/ for Solr that I should use with my .Net project?

Comment: @Yavar but AFAIK you have to setup Solr on a dedicated server that could be a bit of overhead for the limited budget projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To search multiple fields with Lucene.Net, you either manually construct boolean query and add individual field queries to it, or use MultiFieldQueryParser to constructs boolean query for you, or use [query parser syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_0/queryparsersyntax.html). Examples:

1) Manual construction, for 2 fields:

```cs
var query = new BooleanQuery();
Query nameQuery = 
     new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, "ProductName", analyzer).Parse(keyword);
Query descriptionQuery = 
     new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, "ProductDescription", analyzer).Parse(keyword);
query.Add(nameQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
query.Add(descriptionQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
```

2) MultiFieldQueryParser:

```cs
Query query = new MultiFieldQueryParser(                        
                            Version.LUCENE_30,   
                            new string[] { "ProductName", "ProductDescription" },
                            analyzer)
              .Parse(keyword);
```

Answer (score -1):

May be you can also try Fulltext Search Indexing provided by SQL Server.

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer :). User's question is pretty straightforward. He is not asking for suggestion. IF you need to give one it is better to provide it in comments.

Comment: Hi Gijo, I can't use a fulltext search with this client (for political reasons). Thanks anyway.